# Node JS - Systeminformation, cpuTemperature function does not return temperature

Tags: node.js, cpu, system-information

I am working on a project where I want to access and display the temperature of my CPU. I found a tutorial where I via the "systeminformation" package can gain access to mutliple CPU stats. But when I use the cpuTemperature function it does not return the temperature, instead it returns "-1" and empty list and "-1".

```
si.cpuTemperature(function(data) {
  console.log('CPU-Temperature:');
  console.log(data);
});

=> { main: -1, cores: [], max: -1 }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is my CPU not supporting this type of event?

Tutorial I have used: https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are trying that on windows. Accoording to [docs](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation#windows-temperature-battery-) you need to run wmic with admin privileges, if you don't get any data. For OSX and Linux you also need some extra packages installed like osx-temperature-sensor Node module for OSX, and the sensors package (lm-sensors for Debian based) Linux machines. You can try to run node from an Administrator terminal to check out the privilege issue on Windows.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do this on windows, and I am trying to avoid external programs since I want to learn how to do this on my own. Any ideas how I should proceed?

Comment: You got it all wrong. The node module uses wmic under the hood, and administrator privileges is required for that. You need to run your node app as an administrator. That is why I suggested trying it from an admin command line. The linked docs clearly states how to use the module.

Comment: Ah yes it seems like I was not running the terminal as admin.